# How to setup multiple data sources with Spring and jdbcTemplate with XML

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm setting up two different datasource for diff databse in spring-servlet.xml

I have tried multiple solutions provided on sites most of them are for spring-boot.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
    <property name="username" value="***" />
    <property name="password" value="***" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>


    <bean id="dataSourceDev"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
    <property name="username" value="***" />
    <property name="password" value="***" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplateDev" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceDev" />
</bean>
```

In java class -

```
  @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplateDev")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplatedev;*/
```

Comment: Are you getting any issues?

Comment: Yes, this setup doesn't work..what should be the ideal way.. im not able to get anything specific to this..